# How do you access another PHP script in a PHP script?

Tags: php

I have a PHP page that needs to send data to another PHP page during the page execution and receive data back.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Update:

Sorry - meant to say that the second script is on a completely different server and domain.

Like how is Stripe doing it with their PHP option: https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php

Comment: Sorry - meant to say that the second script is on a completely different server and domain.

Comment: @vascowhite nothing... I thought of all the options I could think of (include, cURL), but they were not made for this situation or I didn't want to have to install a package.

Comment: Your options are [curl](http://www.php.net/curl) or [file_get_Contents](http://www.php.net/file_get_contents) try `var_dump(file_get_contents('http://domain/filetoget.php'))`

Comment: This question is very poorly specified. Provide important *details* about what you've tried/investigated and what you need to do *specifically*.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**

Looking at the Stripe source code, you will see they do use cURL (**ApiRequestor.php**):

```
  private function _curlRequest($meth, $absUrl, $headers, $params, $myApiKey)
  {
    $curl = curl_init();
    $meth = strtolower($meth);
    $opts = array();
    if ($meth == 'get') {
      $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPGET] = 1;
      if (count($params) > 0) {
    $encoded = self::encode($params);
    $absUrl = "$absUrl?$encoded";
      }
    } else if ($meth == 'post') {
      $opts[CURLOPT_POST] = 1;
      $opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = self::encode($params);
    } else if ($meth == 'delete')  {
      $opts[CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST] = 'DELETE';
      if (count($params) > 0) {
    $encoded = self::encode($params);
    $absUrl = "$absUrl?$encoded";
      }
    } else {
      throw new Stripe_ApiError("Unrecognized method $meth");
    }

    $absUrl = self::utf8($absUrl);
    $opts[CURLOPT_URL] = $absUrl;
    $opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
    $opts[CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT] = 30;
    $opts[CURLOPT_TIMEOUT] = 80;
    $opts[CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] = true;
    $opts[CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] = $headers;
    $opts[CURLOPT_USERPWD] = $myApiKey . ':';
    $opts[CURLOPT_CAINFO] = dirname(__FILE__) . '/../data/ca-certificates.crt';
    if (!Stripe::$verifySslCerts)
      $opts[CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER] = false;

    curl_setopt_array($curl, $opts);
    $rbody = curl_exec($curl);

    if ($rbody === false) {
      $errno = curl_errno($curl);
      $message = curl_error($curl);
      curl_close($curl);
      $this->handleCurlError($errno, $message);
    }

    $rcode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($curl);
    return array($rbody, $rcode);
  }
```

[cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) - from the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php):

> PHP supports libcurl, a library created by Daniel Stenberg, that
>   allows you to connect and communicate to many different types of
>   servers with many different types of protocols. libcurl currently
>   supports the http, https, ftp, gopher, telnet, dict, file, and ldap
>   protocols. libcurl also supports HTTPS certificates, HTTP POST, HTTP
>   PUT, FTP uploading (this can also be done with PHP's ftp extension),
>   HTTP form based upload, proxies, cookies, and user+password
>   authentication.

```
<?php

/* http://localhost/upload.php:
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
*/

$ch = curl_init();

$data = array('name' => 'Foo', 'file' => '@/home/user/test.png');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/upload.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `include('script2.php')` from script1.php

Then you can call the functions within script2.php (assuming they have global scope) from script1.php.

Comment: Sorry - meant to say that the second script is on a completely different server and domain.

Answer (score 1):

The other possibility if you want to call a PHP script like the end user via URL's, cURL is a good tool to know about.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Stripe seems to be able to do it without a cURL (https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php) how are they doing it?

Comment: I have tried to figure it out... just don't know enough OO PHP to determine how with the certain class they are doing it. I probably should look into that more.